# Finding the fourth roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

How would I find the fourth roots of $-81i$ in the complex numbers?

Here is what I currently have:

$w = -81i$

$r = 9$

$\theta = \arctan (-81)$?

Although I am not sure it's correct or if I am on the right track. May I have some help please?

Comment: Look at the number when drawn on the complex plane.  $-81i$ lies directly on the negative imaginary axis, yes?  So, the original angle of $-81i$ before taking the root is...?  Now, if we were to quarter that angle?  And then look for the other three angles so that the other three and this angle were all evenly spread around the origin?

Comment: Check out roots of complex number here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: Next, look at the magnitude.  $-81i$ lies what... $81$ units away from the origin.  And $81=9^2=3^4$...

Comment: @JMoravitz Would the original angle be pi/2?

Comment: Negative.  Recall that the positive real axis is considered an angle of zero., and angle increases as you go counter-clockwise around, or decreases as you go clockwise around.

Comment: Oh okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w:= -81i = 81 e^{-i\pi/2},81 e^{3i\pi/2}, 81e^{7i\pi/2},81 e^{11i\pi/2},$$ 
So the 4th roots of $w$ are:
$$\sqrt[4]{81} e^{-i\pi/8}, \sqrt[4]{81}e^{3i\pi/8}, \sqrt[4]{81} e^{7i\pi/8}, \sqrt[4]{81} e^{11i\pi/8},$$
Where $\sqrt[4]{81}$ denotes the unique real positive 4th root of 81. By algebraic considerations, we know there are exactly 4 4th roots. So these are all of them.

Comment: Uh... you seem to have ignored the $81$ aspect of it

Comment: Haha, yeah! I'll fix it.

Comment: Oh thank you! But then theta is equal to -pi/8 + (k(pi)/2?

Comment: Correct. Is your question resolved?

Comment: Yes. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: If your question has been resolved, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It is much simpler: the (real) fourth root of $81$ is $3$.  So you simply have to determine the fourth roots of $-i$. For that, use the complex exponential notation:
$$\mathrm e^{4i\theta}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{3i\pi}2},\;\text{ so }\;4\theta\equiv \frac{3\pi}2\bmod 2\pi.$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) Rewrite $-81i$ as $0-81i$.

2) Find the modulus $|z|$ and argument of $0-81i$, using the formulas $$|z| = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$$ and $$\arg \theta = \arctan \dfrac {b}{a}$$

3) Use Demoivre's formula $z^{1/n} = |z|^{1/n} \left(\cos \dfrac {\theta k}{n} + i \sin \dfrac {\theta k}{n}\right)$, $k \in (0,3)$ with the values you've found.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler's formula: If the complex number is $z = \rho e^{i \theta} = \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ (polar coordinates; $\rho, \theta$ are reals), then:

$\begin{align*}
  z^\alpha
    &= \rho^\alpha \cdot e^{i \alpha \theta}
\end{align*}$

In the particular case that $\alpha = 1 / n$ for a natural number $n$, as $e^{i \theta} = e^{i (\theta + 2 k \pi)}$ :

$\begin{align*}
  z^{1/n}
    &= \rho^{1/n} \cdot e^{i (\theta + 2 \pi) / n}
\end{align*}$

I.e., the $n$-th roots are situated on a circle of radius $\rho^{1/n}$ around 0, distributed evenly one at an angle $\theta /n$ and the others $2 \pi / n$ apart. For $n = 4$, they form a square.

Comment: Ahh okay! Thank you!